# Visual Studio 2013 builds take 4 times as long when trying to build using either MSBuild or Incredibuild

Tags: performance, build, msbuild, fusion, incredibuild

For several days I've been building my solution, with 30+ projects and have noticed that when building, rebuilding, or cleaning my solution it a very long time, about 4 times as long as other peers in my team. This occurred when trying to build using MSBuild as well as Incredibuild.

I checked Incredibuild connectivity to server and all the build configurations both on the Incredibuild agent settings as well as in the VS build settings, all values were as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After scanning my computer for viruses and checking sufficient memory, I remembered that I had enabled the Fusion Log in the registry a couple of days earlier.

I solved my slow build time issues immediately once I changed my registry keys back.

The keys changed were:

- EnableLog Key set back to 0 (was 1 beforehand)
- ForceLog Key set back to 0 (was 1 beforehand)

Under the registry node:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion

You can also turn the fusion logging off using the [`FusLogVw.exe` tool found in the Windows SDK folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)